# Reference material (EV/ betting game questions) for Quant Hedge Funds Interviews

Tags: probability, hedge-fund, expected-value, game-theory

I need material to practice EV games questions.But I lack practice in betting questions where a set-up of a game is given and one has to respond to the best strategy or best bet to take. A good book with theory and questions would be great, or even a website to practice probability questions like these.

Comment: The Mathematics of Poker might be a good option. Lots of toy games based on probability and game theory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not directly about quant finance.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, but I have recently interviewed with a Quant Hedge Fund. I gave the aptitude test and did not fare well in the probability section. I just need some practice material for such problems.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of books I have and like:

Pretty much every puzzle style question I got in any interviews I'd seen before, essentially from reading books like these.

[puzzlegrams, pentagram](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0671687409)
Simpler puzzles, nicely illustrated.

[My Best Mathematical and Logic Puzzles (Dover Recreational Math), Marten Gardner](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematical-Logic-Puzzles-Dover-Recreational/dp/0486281523/ref=mp_s_a_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1552939789&sr=8-4&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_FMwebp_QL65&keywords=martin+gardner&dpPl=1&dpID=416KYSEJX8L&ref=plSrch) 
A nice book of shortish puzzles, harder than puzzlegrams, with useful and interesting identities.

[the Incredible Dr Matrix, Martin Gardner](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.amazon.co.uk/Incredible-Dr-Matrix-Martin-Gardner/dp/068414669X&ved=2ahUKEwjpnJfQvIzhAhXrSRUIHS-pBbwQFjAFegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3zSE-WoSpqcsZEKX2VBVGb&cshid=1552939017032)
A book about a numerologist with lots of interesting mathematical oddities, kind of explaining how numerology works in a similar way to how cold reading is explained, by showing how certain patterns of numbers occur.

[Mathematical Magic Show, Marten Gardner](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematical-Magic-Show-Penguin-Mathematics/dp/0140165568&ved=2ahUKEwi0kZa3vYzhAhVkThUIHXUWAqkQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2wHOSwZnWJ6CbgtJTWF0xK) 
More maths puzzles, ranging from really quite hard to nice and neat.

[Mrs. Perkins's Electric Quilt: And Other Intriguing Stories of Mathematical Physics, Paul J. Nahin](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mrs-Perkinss-Electric-Quilt-Mathematical/dp/0691135401&ved=2ahUKEwiNt7WivozhAhXZSxUIHbtSCyEQFjALegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2XbdEIs8RG7dl3no6Z52v1&cshid=1552939559520) 
More interesting mathematical results, but more tied to physics.

I recently moved house so all my books are still in boxes, when i remember others I'll add them to the list.

Comment: Any update on these? Thanks!